# Libre Office and Firefox icons gone on BQ M10 HD tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, firefox, bq, m10

I recently updated my BQ tablet and for some reason the Libre Office icon and the Firefox icon have gone. I can choose Libre Office to open files but I can't create new ones without going into a saved file and clicking on new file. I can't access Firefox at all. Is there a fix for this that works on the tablet version of the OS?

Answer (score 4):

Do you know that new Libertine Scope (with all Ubuntu desktop apps) has been added as part of the Ubuntu Touch OTA-12? You will find LO and Firefox icons there.

The new scope can be activated by swiping up from the bottom of the screen on any scope. You will be in the scope management page. Scroll down until you find the scope named Desktop Apps (the one with the big X as the icon) star it and then move it to just below the Apps scope, and you should be set to go.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly not the answer you may of been looking for but you could try going into the software centre and uninstalling and then installing them again. This should give you your icons back, so at least you can access them easier. As a long term answer. I would log a bug for this in Launchpad so a permanant fix can be given.

Comment: Considering the specificity of Ubuntu Touch, this deprecated habit to reinstall app (an MS Windows reflex) is not advisable.